# Using R and purrr to join multiple dataframes using a list of lists with pmap

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, purrr

I'm trying to join together dataframes that are embedded in a list using pmap.

```
library(purrr)
library(plyr)
# Create a list of 5 data frames
create_df <- function(){
      map(1:5, ~ data.frame(country = c("USA", "CHINA", "JAPAN", "FRANCE"),
                                         col = sample.int(100, 4))
      )
    }
# Create a list of lists
list_of_list_of_dataframes <- map(1:3, ~ create_df())
# join the first element of the 3 lists together. 
list_of_dataframes <- pmap(list_of_list_of_dataframes, join_all, by = 'country', type = 'left')
```

The problem that I have is that this `join_all` function from plyr doesn't seem to work. I get the error:
`Error in .f(.l[[c(1L, i)]], .l[[c(2L, i)]], .l[[c(3L, i)]], ...) : 
  unused argument (.l[[c(3, i)]])`

I am able to do `list_of_dataframes <- pmap(list_of_list_of_dataframes, cbind)` to bind the data frames together but it doesn't delete the index columns that I'm matching too and assumes that the order of the left columns is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dplyr's left_join + purrr's reduce and map2. But it is less readable than @Tung's answer.

```
reduce(list_of_list_of_dataframes, map2, left_join, by = "country")
[[1]]
  country col.x col.y col
1     USA    82    31  59
2   CHINA     7    65  29
3   JAPAN    62    58  52
4  FRANCE    70    88  35

[[2]]
  country col.x col.y col
1     USA    17    77  23
2   CHINA     5    86  92
3   JAPAN    70    55  73
4  FRANCE    68    42  13

[[3]]
  country col.x col.y col
1     USA    51    10  20
2   CHINA    60    82  65
3   JAPAN    65    90  56
4  FRANCE    64    30  10

[[4]]
  country col.x col.y col
1     USA     9    53  36
2   CHINA    60     5  89
3   JAPAN    51    88  69
4  FRANCE     6    14  11

[[5]]
  country col.x col.y col
1     USA    63    30  94
2   CHINA    92    16  21
3   JAPAN    11    52  27
4  FRANCE    58   100  66
```

Comment: This won't provide OP's expected output `list_of_dataframes <- pmap(list_of_list_of_dataframes, cbind)`

Comment: @phiver This is perfect. The example column names aren't great because they're all the same but the data.frames I'll be working with will have unique column names so this should work just perfect thanks!

Comment: @phiver: can you explain what `map2` is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use `bind_cols` and then `select` only desired columns

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123456)

# Create a list of 5 data frames
create_df <- function(){
  map(1:5, ~ data.frame(country = c("USA", "CHINA", "JAPAN", "FRANCE"),
                        col = sample.int(100, 4))
  )
}

# Create a list of lists
list_of_list_of_dataframes <- map(1:3, ~ create_df())
str(list_of_list_of_dataframes, max.level = 1)

#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 5
#>  $ :List of 5
#>  $ :List of 5

pmap(list_of_list_of_dataframes, bind_cols) %>% 
  map(~ select(.x, country, matches("col")))

#> [[1]]
#>   country col col1 col2
#> 1     USA  80   16   23
#> 2   CHINA  75    8   74
#> 3   JAPAN  39   13   88
#> 4  FRANCE  34   17   29
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   country col col1 col2
#> 1     USA  37   48   52
#> 2   CHINA  20   70   44
#> 3   JAPAN  53   87   57
#> 4  FRANCE  10   86   72
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   country col col1 col2
#> 1     USA  99   86   68
#> 2   CHINA  17   17   36
#> 3   JAPAN  79   52   33
#> 4  FRANCE  58   85   73
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   country col col1 col2
#> 1     USA  91   24   51
#> 2   CHINA  88   12   86
#> 3   JAPAN  98   81   75
#> 4  FRANCE  87    8   94
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   country col col1 col2
#> 1     USA  88   96   84
#> 2   CHINA  20   87   83
#> 3   JAPAN  33   70   27
#> 4  FRANCE  76   59   18
```

Created on 2018-07-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).